# Ideas for this integral: $\int \frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sin{x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sin{x}} \mathrm{d}x$$

So I was wondering if this correctly by converting $\sqrt{\tan{x}}$ into $\frac{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}$ therefore I can divide it with $\sin{x}$ and that will give me $\frac{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}$ and that will be $\sqrt{\cot{x}}$ so the integral is formed into $\displaystyle \int \sqrt{\cot x}\mathrm{d}x $. Is this so far correctly done?

Comment: it would make $1/\sqrt{sinxcosx}$

Comment: No it has not been simplified correctly. $\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x} = \frac 1{\sqrt{\sin x \cos x}} = \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt {\csc 2x}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you can divide the fraction by $\sin x$? I don't understand.

Comment: never mind, I did an absurd silly mistake :( .

Comment: This is a special integral (incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind):

Comment: mistakes happen but dont delete this question, i want to see someone do it

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Yes, it's the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind, well said!

Comment: @EM4 are you sure this is an indefinite integral, i.e., there are no limits?

Comment: I made this problem up in my head, i got excited by $\int \sqrt{tan{x}} dx$ and I was like hmmm can this happen. Until I seen my error and @AnindyaPrithvi stated.

Comment: @an4s yes it is indefinite integral

Comment: haha xD, by the way, try $\int \sqrt{sinx} dx$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349654/how-do-i-evaluate-this-integral-int-pi-4-pi-3-frac-sqrt-tan-x-si) is not _exactly_ a duplicate since your integral is indefinite but might still be of interest to you.

Comment: $-\sqrt{\sin (2 x)} \sqrt{\tan (x)} \csc (x) F\left(\left.\frac{\pi }{4}-x\right|2\right)$ where F is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind

Answer (score 5):

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sin x} dx$$
Let $\tan x =t^2 \implies \sec^2 x dx=2t dt$
Then $$I=\int \frac{2}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} dt$$
This can be found interms of Elliptic functions.

Comment: B&F 263.50: $I=F(2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\tan x},m=1/2)$

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{\tan{x}}}{\sin{x}} dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)}} dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)}}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\sin\left(2x\right)}}dx$$

Substituting $t=2x$ you have $dx=\frac 12dt$:

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\sin\left(t\right)}}$$

where the last integral can be reduced to a complete elliptical integral of first species.

Comment: where you found the 2x?

Comment: I dived for $\sqrt2$ numerator and denominator. Put $\sqrt2$ into $\sqrt{\cos(x)\sin(x)}$, i.e. $\sqrt{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\sqrt{\sin(2x)}$. Hence $2x=t$.